# How to handle updates to a WPF DataGrid manually?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The Items for my DataGrid is an IList.  The only way the IList is updated is via methods on the class of which it is a property.

```
class SomeObject
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<SomeType> Items { get; }

    public void AddItem(SomeType someType);

    public event Action<SomeType> ItemAdded;
}
```

The list itself is a read-only collection and cannot be updated directly - iow, it is definitely not an ObservableCollection.  Is there a way I can bind to the DataGrid for display purposes, but handle the create, update, and delete to the items myself using binding/datagrid hooks of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a proxy for your collection that implements both IBindingList and ICancelAddNew.  With these two you can "intercept" calls to add new items and remove existing ones.  The method AddNew() is called when a new item is added, and Remove/RemoveAt is called when an item is deleted.  Instead of directly modifying the collection, at these times you can call API methods designed for that purpose.  Below is the minimal implementation required.  Note a few things:

1. New items are not immediately added to the collection - the are stored temporarily in a _newItem field
2. If escape is hit while editing a new item, first CancelNew, then EndNew is called
3. It is assumed 'Items' is an observable collection, the events from which trigger corresponding ListChanged events
4. This technique doesn't provide a means to intercept edits made to properties of existing items

...

```
class SomeTypeBindingList : IBindingList, ICancelAddNew
{
    public SomeTypeBindingList(SomeObject someObject)
    {
        _someObject = someObject;

        var observableCollection = _someObject.Items as ObservableCollection<SomeType>;
        if (observableCollection != null)
            observableCollection.CollectionChanged += ObservableCollectionOnCollectionChanged;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new SomeTypeEnumerator(this);
    }

    public int Count => _someObject.Items.Count + (_newItem == null ? 0 : 1);

    public object SyncRoot { get; } = new object();

    public bool IsSynchronized { get; } = false;

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        return IndexOf(value) != -1;
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(value, _newItem))
            return _someObject.Items.Count;

        return _someObject.Items.IndexOf((SomeType)value);
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        var someType = (SomeType)value;
        _someObject.RemoveItem(someType);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        var someType = _someObject.Items[index];
        _someObject.RemoveItem(someType);
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= _someObject.Items.Count)
            {
                if(_newItem == null)
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                return _newItem;
            }

            return _someObject.Items[index];
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public object AddNew()
    {
        _newItem = new SomeType();

        ListChanged?.Invoke(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemAdded, _someObject.Items.Count));
        return _newItem;
    }

    public void CancelNew(int itemIndex)
    {
        _newItem = null;
        ListChanged?.Invoke(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemDeleted, itemIndex));
    }

    public void EndNew(int itemIndex)
    {
        if (_newItem != null)
        {
            var someType = _newItem;
            _newItem = null;
            _someObject.AddItem(someType);
        }
    }

    private void ObservableCollectionOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            Enumerable.Range(e.OldStartingIndex, e.OldItems.Count).ForEach(i => ListChanged?.Invoke(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemDeleted, i)));
        else if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            Enumerable.Range(e.NewStartingIndex, e.NewItems.Count).ForEach(i => ListChanged?.Invoke(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.ItemAdded, i)));
    }

    private readonly SomeObject _someObject;
    private SomeType _newItem;

    class SomeTypeEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        public SomeTypeEnumerator(SomeObject someObject)
        {
            _someObject = someObject;
            Reset();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _index++;
            return _someObject.Items.Count < _index;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _index = -1;
        }

        public object Current => _someObject.Items[_index];

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        private readonly SomeObject _someObject;
        private int _index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `ItemsSource` property of a `DataGrid` to any public *property* that returns an `IEnumerable`, inclucing an `IList<T>` property. You can not bind to fields though so you should make `Items` a property if you intend to bind to it:

```
public IList<SomeType> Items { get; private set; }
```

But for you to be able to add items to the source collection dynamically at runtime and have the new items automatically show up in the DataGrid, the source collection must implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. Only the `ObservableCollection<T>` class does this in the .NET Framework. A `List<T>` does not.

And an `IList<T>` is not a read-only collection since it has an Add method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. So I guess you might as well use an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

**Edit:**

If you really want to refesh the `DataGrid` "manually" you could subscribe to the `ItemAdded` event of your object in the code-behind of the view and use the `UpdateTarget()` method of the `BindingExpression`:

```
someObject.ItemAdded += (se, ee) => 
{
    var be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(theDataGrid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty);
    if (be != null)
        be.UpdateTarget();

};
```

Or you could just reset the `ItemsSource` property:

```
someObject.ItemAdded += (se, ee) => 
{
    theDataGrid.ItemsSource = someObject.Items;

};
```

**Edit 2:**

> My issue is that I need a reliable way to intercept the outbound binding mechanism of the grid so that I can call AddItem() when a new row is added, for example. I've experimented with IBindingList to see if I could use that, but as of yet it has not panned out.

If you bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection<SomeType>`, you could handle the `CollectionChanged` event of this collection:

```
observableCollection.CollectionChanged += (ss, ee) =>
{
    if(ee.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        SomeType newItem = ee.NewItems[0] as SomeType;
        someObject.AddItem(newItem);
    }
};
```

This event will be raised when the `DataGrid` adds a new item to the source collection.

Comment: Thanks I updated my example based on your feedback.  The point is I can't make changes to Items, but I still want to use DataGrid functionality for editing existing items and for creating new ones.  But these only seem to function when you use built-in binding.

Comment: You "can't change" the Items collection but yet you want to be able to create new items and add them to to it? This makes no sense. If you want to be able to edit the items in a collection you should set the or bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to this collection. Create another collection to bind to if you don't want to add items to the Items collection.

Comment: The example class above is an simplification of an existing API I have to code to.  The object contains a collection that you can read, but making modifications to it requires you call a method, like AddItem() for example.

Comment: Then you obviously can't use bind this collection to the DataGrid since it won't be able to add any items to a read-only collection. This should be pretty clear so what is your issue? Bind to another collection or implement the add functionality yourself.

Comment: Yes!..that's exactly my point.  I can bind the collection all day long.  If SomeObject makes a change to the collection (assuming the collection also implements INotify...), an event will be raised and the grid will get updated.  My issue is that I need a reliable way to intercept the outbound binding mechanism of the grid so that I can call AddItem() when a new row is added, for example.  I've experimented with IBindingList to see if I could use that, but as of yet it has not panned out.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Bind to an ObservableCollection<T> and handle its CollectionChanged event. See my edited answer for an example.

Comment: I considered this, but it means that every SomeType would be stored twice - once in the original collection and once in the "proxy" ObservableCollection.  Not a problem for a handful of items, but it seems wasteful for thousands of items.